# Listing vs. counting perfect matchings in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, convex-optimization, polyhedra, matching-theory

In his [Polyhedral Computation](https://www.research-collection.ethz.ch/bitstream/handle/20.500.11850/426218/PolyCompBook20200829.pdf) textbook, Fukuda writes:

> It is known that the counting problem [of perfect matchings] is #P-complete even for bipartite graphs. There are polynomial algorithms for the listing problem.

But, if I can list all matchings efficiently, I also can count them efficiently (right?). Seems I'm missing something, but I don't see what... (and I'm not very familiar with the #P-complete class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complexity of counting and of listing is evaluated differently. An algorithm listing all the possibilities is usually called an [enumeration algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumeration_algorithm). (This can be confusing because outside computer science, "enumeration" can also refer to counting, as in "enumerative combinatorics".)

When we want to list all the perfect matchings, a polynomial-time algorithm is an algorithm with a [*polynomial-time delay*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_delay) between matchings. In other words, we want an algorithm that goes through all the matchings one at a time, such that the time between listing consecutive matchings is bounded by a polynomial in the input size.

This would also give us a polynomial-time algorithm for counting perfect matchings if the total number of matchings were polynomial. However, in some cases, it can be exponential or worse; for example, the complete bipartite graph $K_{n,n}$ has $n!$ perfect matchings. So even if we can list all those matchings with only a polynomial delay between each one and the next (and even if it took us only $O(1)$ time at every step!) it will take us too long to count them that way.